# How do iPhone apps like Chase or Lemon use the camera to scan and gather information from the image?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, camera, mobile-application

I am really interested in building an app that uses a phone's native camera to snap a photo and gather information from that photo.  Examples of something like this is the Chase banking app that allows users to snap a photo of their check and then it processes it and deposits it. Also the Lemon app that takes photos of what is in your wallet and then stores them in the app.  Is there a Library out there for this type of thing? or is it all custom done? And if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to look for OCR (optical character recognition) libraries for iOS.

The answer below might help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062755/ocroptical-character-recoginition-libraries-for-iphone